# How to encode with a JSON multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I have this kind of array:

```
array {
    [0] => {"ID":"343","name":"John","money":"3000"}
    [1] => {"ID":"344","name":"Erik","money":"2000"}
    [2] => {"ID":"346","name":"Ronny","money":"3300"}
}
```

And I want to read it from PHP to JavaScript with JSON. As you can see, the inner array is already encoded as follows:

```
json_encode($a)
```

To be readable from my JavaScript code, I want it with the following syntax:

```
"[0]" : "{"ID":"343","name":"John","money":"3000"}",
"[1]" : "{"ID":"344","name":"Eric","money":"2000"}",
"[2]" : "{"ID":"345","name":"Ronny","money":"3300"}",
```

How can I do that?

Comment: php json_encode() will be decoded by jquery jQuery.parseJSON()

Comment: Use jsonlint.com to validate you JSON - I see some problems.

Comment: Usually doesn't make sense to encode the inner arrays by themselves. Is there a reason for doing that instead of encoding everything at once?

Answer (score 3):

In your title, you ask **How to encode with a JSON multidimensional array**. I am going to assume that is your real question, because your question body asks something different. Assuming you have an array `$arr`, do not call `json_encode()` on each inner array `$a`.

Instead, simply call `json_encode($arr)` and it will encode the entire array, including inner arrays.

```
$arr = array (

    array ("ID" => "343", "name" => "John", "money" => "3000"),
    array ("ID" => "344", "name" => "Erik", "money" => "2000"),
    array ("ID" => "346", "name" => "Ronny", "money" => "3300")

);

$j = json_encode($arr);
```

`$j` will be something like this:

```
[{"ID":"343","name":"John","money":"3000"},
{"ID":"344","name":"Erik","money":"2000"},
{"ID":"346","name":"Ronny","money":"3300"}]
```

You can parse this quite easily using `jQuery.parseJSON()`. Then you can simply loop through the parsed array to get what you want from the inner arrays.

```
var arr = jQuery.parseJSON('[{"ID":"343","name":"John","money":"3000"},{"ID":"344","name":"Erik","money":"2000"},{"ID":"346","name":"Ronny","money":"3300"}]');

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var a = arr[i]; // Inner array.

    console.log(a.ID);
    console.log(a.name);
    console.log(a.money);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array(
      '[0]' => '{"ID":"343","name":"John","money":"3000"}',
      '[1]' => '{"ID":"344","name":"Erik","money":"2000"}',
      '[2]' => '{"ID":"346","name":"Ronny","money":"3300"}'
     );
echo json_encode($arr);
```